# Remove only something on a text document (VB.NET 4.8)

Tags: vb.net

my question looks complicated but it is not so complicated. I have a text document with this in it:

REMOVE

REMOVE

REMOVE

REMOVE

KEEP

KEEP

ect. for the KEEP

I would like to remove only the REMOVE and keep the KEEP with no space.
How to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this document a file or a TextBox?

Comment: So are we literally looking for "REMOVE" and "KEEP", or are you asking how you remove the first 4 lines of a file?  You basically have two options when changing a text file: (1) Write to a temp file, delete the original, rename the temp, or (2) Read entire file into memory (using maybe a List(of String)), modify the List, overwrite the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your code file...

```
Imports System.IO
```

Then we can use the `File` class that is in this namespace. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netcore-3.1

```
Private Sub RemoveRemove()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\KeepRemove.txt")
    Dim KeepLines As New List(Of String)
    For Each line In lines
        If line.StartsWith("KEEP") Then
            KeepLines.Add(line)
        End If
    Next
    File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\Keep.txt", String.Join(vbCrLf, KeepLines))
End Sub
```

Comment: @Mary FWIW, you could use the [WriteAllLines(String, IEnumerable<String>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_WriteAllLines_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) method to avoid the String.Join.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FileOpen(1, "file.txt", OpenMode.Input)

    Dim S As String = "REMOVE"
    While S = "REMOVE"
       S = Trim(LineInput(1))
    End While

    Dim newTxt As String = S + vbCr

    While Not EOF(1)
       newTxt += Trim(LineInput(1)) + vbCr
    End While
     FileClose(1)
     FileOpen(1, "file.txt", OpenMode.Output)
     Print(1, newTxt)
     FileClose(1)
```

Comment: I have tried this code but it does nothing. How to use it? Thank you!

Comment: It has been a very long time since I have used the vb6 file stuff. I would rather see a .net solution.

Comment: Assuming that your document is in "file.txt" and that it contains text that you wrote in question, it should overwrite the file keeping only the "KEEP" lines.